# How to do arithmetic in Spring properties?

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="Job1" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="1" />
    </bean>
```

I want to load `value` from a property file (`value = "${jobs.per.second}`"), which will be manipulated.

For example: `jobs.properties` file will have: `jobs.per.second = 500`

I want to use arithmetic operations (invert it and multiply it by 1000) (1/500 * 1000 = 2)
and substitute `value = 2` instead of 1.

How do I go about it? Is there any way to enable arithmetic operations in xml?

EDIT: I am using Spring 3.

Comment: Does [this][1] question and solution help?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953468/performing-arithmetic-using-spring-expression-language-and-propertyplaceholderco

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You didn't mention which version of Spring you're using, but Spring 3.0 comes with Spring EL (Expression Language) which allows you to use expressions in the XML bean definitions (as well as other places, such as @Value annotations).

```
<util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:jobs.properties"/>
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="Job1" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="#{ 1000 / properties['jobs.per.second'] * 100.0 }" />
</bean>
```

You can read more about Spring EL [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

Comment: Yes, it is Spring 3. I am able to resolve the issue. This will definitely help others with similar issues.

Comment: Do you happen to know, how it works together with property placeholder configurer? Can I use "#{ 1000 / ${jobs.per.second} * 100.0 }" ?

Comment: Spring 4, `<property name="repeatInterval" value="#{ 1000 / ${jobs.per.second} * 100.0 }" />` works with no issues. Might work with spring 3 also.