# How to do arithmetic in Spring properties, with values from a properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Example use-case: properties file passes in a numeric value in millis, and you want to use it in seconds.

Your .properties file:

> jdbc.timeout= 2000

Your applicationContext.xml currently

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">       
   <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />        
   <property name="url"value="jdbc:mysql://myserver/mydb" />
   <property name="username" value="user" />        
   <property name="password" value="changeme" />        
   <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1;"/>         
   <property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="${jdbc.timeout}" />
</bean>
```

You want the validationQueryTimeout value to be in seconds, how do you convert it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using Spring 3.0 or later, you can use the property inside the SpEL expression like this:

```
   <property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="#{${jdbc.timeout}/1000}" />
```

Comment: Also see another approach presented here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909475/how-to-do-arithmetic-in-spring-properties

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for similar arithmetic operation in `@Value`, can be done by `#{${someProperty} + 2}`. 
In this case `@Value(#{${jdbc.timeout} / 1000})`